# 1N4004 SMD replacment

Tags: surface-mount

Please help me, how do I find the corresponding equaivalent of 1N4004 Diode. Also as not everything is available in local market here in India, I would appreciate, if there are some well known alternatives. Please help, I have a software background, not good at electronics.

Comment: have y9u tried contacting the local distributors and sources? This can be done online.

Comment: sorry moderators but this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're in India, so I assume most of the supply is coming from mainland China.

The usual part I suggest for low-cost 'series' production is the 'M' series. In your case, it would be an [M4](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/34043/WTE/M4-T1/+2_1WWUyRD/1MBwVA+/datasheet.pdf). It is equivalent to a 1N4004 in an SMA package.

[image]

Of course thermally they're a little different.

Answer (score 0):

ON Semi has the MRA4004 which is in an SMA package.

http://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/product.do?id=MRA4004